# How to run awk on a file with cedella as delimiter

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with below contents

```
cat file1.dat
    anuÇ89Çhyd
    binduÇ45Çchennai
```

I would like to print the second column with Ç as delimiter.
output should be
89
45

Answer (score 1):

The manpage of `awk` mentions the following:

```
    -F fs
    --field-separator fs
         Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).
```

So, this command does what you want:

```
cat file1.dat | awk -F'Ç' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: @EdMorton: although my answer worked on my system (Linux subsystem for Windows), I've adapted it according to your proposal.

Comment: Your answer would work but it just contained 2 bad habits - 1) `cat file | command` is a [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and 2) you should always single-quote strings in shell unless you **need** to not do so, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file
anuÇ89Çhyd
binduÇ45Çchennai
```

You can use `cut`:

```
$ cut -f 2 -d 'Ç' file
```

`awk`:

```
$ awk -F'Ç' '{print $2}' file
```

`sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/^[^Ç]*Ç([^Ç]*).*/\1/' file
```

GNU grep:

```
$ grep -oP '^[^Ç]*Ç\K[^Ç]+(?=Ç)' file
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -lnE 'print $1 if /^[^Ç]*Ç([^Ç]+)Ç/' file
```

All those print:

```
89
45
```